# Elastic search is not accessible running in AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, ip

I'm running elastic search in AWS t2.micro instance in port 9200 and it has a security-group `launch-wizard-7` and that security group has all inbound traffic in all ports from anywhere. but still i'm not able to access it with public IPv4 or Public DNS.

Comment: Some things to check: Are you able to curl localhost:9200 from within the instance and see a response ? Are you able to ping your instance’s public IP ? Probably not a good idea to configure security group open to world. Atleast restrict all inbound traffic to only your public IP

Comment: Yes, i'm able to curl... but i'm not able to ping public IP.

Comment: Does your security group have a rule to allow ICMP ? If not, allow ICMP and try again ? Ping uses ICMP

Comment: ICMP? where?@ben5556

Comment: ICMP on the instance security group but please look at the below answer first and check if that helps.

Comment: Thanks @ben5556 .. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you need to configure your elasticsearch to use your public IP by default uses the loopback address, this could be done setting the property network.host in the elasticsearch config file for more details see

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html

I hope this helps

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks, I wasted around 4 hours for this.